# word for : something that is obtained after purification process

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine a liquid mixture containing many components and now by some process vital element in the liquid is seperated from the rest of the mixture. 
What term do we use for the obtained element?. If I know correctly Arabic word for that is *safa*.

*Purified*, *distilled*, *condensed* are some of the words which I can think of. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: We would only very rarely use 'element' in a non-chemical sense when talking about chemistry. // A substance isolated from a mixture is called an _extract_.

Comment: Also maybe 'precipitate'?

Answer (score 2):

I think [residue](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/residue) may fit in the context described: (from TFD)

> - Matter remaining after completion of an abstractive chemical or physical process, such as evaporation, combustion, distillation, or filtration; residuum.

Comment: Filtration refers to the process, not the element obtained through the process.

Comment: _Residue_ seems to be the opposite of what the asker is looking for. When you apply some kind of process to extract one particular substance from a compound substance, the residue is _the rest of the stuff_ that’s left behind when the desired substance has been extracted. The asker is looking for the part that’s _not_ residue, the part that was extracted out.

Answer (score 1):

A substance extracted or concentrated by distillation is called a [distillate.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distillate)

If the substance (x) has been rendered pure by your extraction process and the purity of the element is the information that you wish to convey then you can just say you have a quantity of pure x.

Answer (score 0):

[What about **Extraction**?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUikW.jpg)

[Dictionary reference:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/extract)

Answer (score 0):

Isolate.
There are a lot of purifying methods, but  [pure results of a successful purification process are termed **isolate**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_purification_methods_in_chemistry).